# Visual Studio error csc exe exited with code 1073741819

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I opened an API project that I literally changed yesterday and today when I changed a line of code to take in a data from SQL Visual Studio gave me an error with code 1073741819 and not much else information. I tried searching online and tried cleaning and rebuilding and it didn't work. I tried deleting the obj, bin and package folder and it did not work as well. Please help me out as this happened suddenly and I don't know what to do. My version of Visual Studio is Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.5.6. I also tried updating my .net frameworks and .net distribution framework and it still didn't work. Thanks for the future help!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? I've had situations before where msbuild processes have piled up, leading to some very odd behaviour. (I'd suggest updating VS to the latest version too, which is 15.7.X now.)

Comment: just reinstall .net via

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/framework

Comment: omg @JonSkeet you're right. I never restart my computer and i'm not really that into asp.net other than basic api use so this really confused the heck out of me. Thank you!

Comment: update to VS2017 15.7.3 and look if it works

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem before as well.  Restarting Visual Studio occasionally causes `csc.exe` to return a different non-zero (error) number, but is insufficient to clear the error.

One possible cause that I have found is the process `VBCSCompiler.exe` continues to run, even when Visual Studio is closed.  I have found the following steps more quickly remedy the problem *without* rebooting:

- Close all instances of Visual Studio
- Open the Windows Task Manager
- End any active `VBCSCompiler.exe` process(es)

Upon re-launching Visual Studio, the `csc.exe` exit code error should be resolved.